# How to remove context menu items or change right click behaviour?

Tags: mouse, gedit

Is there any way to remove or disable the 'undo' and 'redo' options in the right click context menu for gedit?
Another suitable solution would be to disable the 'click on release' mouse feature. So many times I've been doing something in gedit, I right click to copy something, let go of the mouse button while the pointer is over 'undo' or 'redo' resulting in the loss of a edit history.
It's not so simple as just undoing whatever change i just made. When it's a tedious log file where there's lots of repetitive data, it's hard to tell where I was.

Comment: You can't disable the "click on release" (there's even a bug report in gtk if I remember correctly) and - afaik - you can't remove/disable the undo/redo options unless you are willing to patch the source code.